# How to add only new annotations on MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotation

On MKMapView i have for example 100 annotations. When i zoom out the map i need to update only ten new annontations. But the system updates 110 annotations.    How to add  only new annotations on MKMapView ?

Comment: that depends. how are you creating a new annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `[mapView addAnnotations:additionalAnnotations]` ? (where additionalAnnotations is an array of the 'new' annotations)